# What accounts for the current vacillation in this JK latch?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, simulation, flipflop, latch

After trying a few different simulators (many of which didn't work for this) I was finally able to model a JK latch with NOR gates. Here is an example:

[image]

A weird thing seems to happen though (at least to me). When changing one of the logic inputs to use it "like an SR" latch, there seems to be current fluctuations between it reaches the steady state. Here is a video showing what I'm talking about:

https://gyazo.com/4a4fa7b61369367d7e6ba6dc032d1eb3

[Falstad link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0AL+128+144+80+144+0+0+false+5+0%0AL+80+80+32+80+0+1+false+5+0%0AL+128+32+80+32+0+1+false+5+0%0A150+176+32+320+32+0+3+0+5%0A150+160+144+336+144+0+3+0+5%0Aw+80+80+160+80+0%0Aw+160+80+160+128+0%0Aw+160+80+160+48+0%0Aw+160+48+176+48+0%0Aw+320+32+336+32+0%0A153+336+128+464+128+0+2+5+5%0A153+336+48+464+48+0+2+0+5%0Aw+464+48+336+112+0%0Aw+336+64+464+128+0%0Aw+464+128+512+128+0%0Aw+464+48+512+48+0%0AM+576+48+640+48+0+2.5%0AM+576+128+640+128+0+2.5%0A181+512+128+576+128+0+300+100+120+0.4+0.4%0A181+512+48+576+48+0+300+100+120+0.4+0.4%0Aw+128+144+160+144+0%0Aw+128+32+176+32+0%0Aw+464+128+464+208+0%0Aw+464+208+160+208+0%0Aw+160+208+160+160+0%0Aw+176+-16+176+16+0%0Aw+448+-16+176+-16+0%0Aw+448+-16+464+48+0%0A)

Why does this occur, and what exactly is occurring when it's 'flickering' ?

Comment: I guess, the CLK has to pass only a short pulse on transient. And this is not a NOR JK FF, you have ANDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flickering happens when the output changes from 1 to 0 because the two inputs to the NOR gate take different delyas to arrive.

Consider Q=1.
In this state the two inputs at the top NOR gate are 0,0.
The output will change to 0 if any of these inputs become 1.

Now put J=0,K=1 and apply clock:
First, it can happen that the clock reaches the top NOR input quickly and turns it off.
Then, the Q output fedback to the top AND gate makes its output low and turns on the NOR gate again.

So far, the Q' output of bottom NOR gate hasn't changed, it remained at 0. When this output changes to 1, the flickering of the top NOR ends and the Q output becomes a stable 0.